# Calculator gives unit vector, how to derive vector given only unit vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, diagonalization

My CAS HP Prime calculator gives only unit vectors when I use the function for Eigenvectors. I know how to find a unit vector, $u=\frac{v}{||v||}$, but that doesn't seem to help.

For example:

Eigenvector$\begin{pmatrix}1.25&0.75\\ 0.75&1.25\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow P=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{pmatrix}, D=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&0.5\end{pmatrix}$

Is there a quick trick to get the full vector $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$ instead of a unit vector? (Aside from multiplying P by $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$).

A trick that can be applied to something like this too, to derive the full vector instead of unit vector, my calculator gives the following:

Eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix}8&12&-18\\ 4&18&-20\\ 4&13&-15\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow P= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{849027}{1166876} & \frac{1013883}{347759} & \frac{3880899}{1372105}\\ \frac{283009}{583438} & \frac{1013883}{347759} & \frac{7095941}{1254397}\\\frac{283099}{583438} & \frac{1013883}{347759} & \frac{5488420}{1293633}\end{pmatrix}, D=\begin{pmatrix}4&0&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&5\end{pmatrix}$ .

Want to get P = $\begin{pmatrix}3&1&2\\ 2&1&4\\ 2&1&3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: If you get a common denominator for each column vector (using LCM of the denominator values), then you can easily get $P$ as desired.

Comment: See https://www.hpmuseum.org/forum/archive/index.php?thread-1698.html and https://www.hpmuseum.org/forum/archive/index.php?thread-3482.html

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, thank you. Didn't learn about Jordan in my syllabus (or was a small part that was missed). Though Jordan gave a slightly different value: $\begin{pmatrix}-3&-1&2\\ -2&-1&4\\ -2&-1&3\end{pmatrix}$ which is slightly different & not equivalent to the answer $\begin{pmatrix}3&1&2\\ 2&1&4\\ 2&1&3\end{pmatrix}$. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like Euclid's algorithm:
Take the difference between terms, and difference between differences.  When a difference is much much smaller, assume it is zero.
Take the smallest of the reasonable-sized differences as your unit, and divide each of the original terms by that.  Then round to the nearest integers.
A faster method is to simply divide the vector by its smallest nonzero entry, and round to the nearest simple rational numbers.

Comment: If necessary, continued fractions help to find the nearest simple rational number.

Comment: Thanks, feels like that'd take a long time, and quite error prone, especially with $\begin{pmatrix}8&12&-18\\ 4&18&-20\\ 4&13&-15\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow P= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{849027}{1166876} & \frac{1013883}{347759} & \frac{3880899}{1372105}\\ \frac{283009}{583438} & \frac{1013883}{347759} & \frac{7095941}{1254397}\\\frac{283099}{583438} & \frac{1013883}{347759} & \frac{5488420}{1293633}\end{pmatrix}, D=\begin{pmatrix}4&0&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&5\end{pmatrix}$..?

Comment: The first colum of P becomes (1.5,1,1.000318), the second becomes (1,1,1) and the third (1,2,1.5)